# ERROR 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

***ERROR Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'***
***'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules***
*The Problem is in second await at the .then() Fuction.*
*I am using firebase v9 and that's why setting doc is caughting me off guard.*
This is my script

````
    ////.....
    event.preventDefault();
    setProcessing(true);

    const payload = await stripe
      .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
        },
      })
      .then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
        // payment intent = the payment confirmation ... term used by stripe
        await setDoc(doc(db, "users", user?.uid, "orders", paymentIntent.id),{
          cart: cart,
          amount: paymentIntent.amount,
          created: paymentIntent.created,
        });

        setSucceeded(true);
        setError(null);
        setProcessing(false);

        dispatch({
          type: "EMPTY_CART",
        });

        history.replace("/orders");
      });
  };```


**Ignore this part**
bjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfajabjbk.hjnodvhguhaHjhvguhgnfuahlkaouehgijokjghaksjfiuasfoafujejfaoijoifjaofjaoijfiajlkamufhanfanfuhafokajfa0fjekfaohfaklfafnaokjfajfkajofjaofjkjanajfajfklapajfpoapjlkajflkjdfoakjflkajfpaojfalkfaioejfaijfafkpakfakfaja
````

Comment: Use `.then( async ({ paymentIntend }) => { ...`, so you declare the lambda as async function.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to mix use of `then` and `await`.  You should be able to use one or the other. The main point of async/await is to avoid use of `then` callbacks entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we choose either `then` or `await` in our code, not both of them.

To use `then`, your code should be:

```
promise.then(a => {do some synchronize work})
```

To use `await`, your code should be:

```
// inside an async function
declare a promise p_1;
const resultOfPromise = await p_1;
Do other synchronize work
```